# Strings generated based on an input number?

Tags: python

I'm a begginer programmer and I want to write a simple program that first you give it an int seed, and based on the seed, program generates a string of given parameters. Of course if i give it this same seed in the future i want to see the same value. How do I do that?

Edit : I have a dictionary, argument is a letter from alphabet, and value is this generated string. First, I give it a seed and based on the seed, for eg. "1" program generates value for "a": "ah2". I give it 2 and it generates an another  3 letter string based on 2. (the value doesn't have to go to the dictionary right away, I just want that string generated based on input given.) Is it even possible to code it for a begginer?

Comment: Which parameters would be? There can't be a good answer without knowing the full scope of the problem. It would be nice to have a pseudocode example or at least a basic idea of the full problem.

Comment: Show some code, what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you give an example of what you have in mind? The answer to your question depends on the algorithm generating your strings - I don't quite understand what algorithm you're building that is based on a seed value but might result in different outcomes for the same seed?

Comment: I gave my post more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey hope it can give you a hint or solve your problem:

```
import random
import string

def randomString(stringLength=10,seed=0):
     letters = string.ascii_lowercase
     random.seed(seed)
     return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))
```

Comment: Thank you! This was what i was looking for.